# Heston Model Calibration with MatLab: model prices do not fall in the bid-ask range

Tags: programming, calibration, heston, call, bid

I am currently implementing the MatLab code reported below for the calibration of Heston Model. The code seems fine and, by reading the paper where I took the code, I was able to calibrate and price obtaining exactly the same results as the paper.

Then I have tried to use the same code for call options on SP500 but I could not obtain the same results as it was from the data of the paper. In particular, when I try to price the model prices always fall outside the bid-ask range.

My question then is why this happens? I guess something must be wrong with the data (attached find both paper data and my SP500 data)

[image] [image]

```
function cost = costf(x)
global data; global finalcost;

% Compute individual differences
% Sum of squares performed by Matlab's lsqnonlin
for i=1:length(data)
cost(i)= data(i,5) - call_heston_cf(data(i,1),x(1), x(2), (x(5)+x(3)^2)/(2*x(2)), x(3), data(i,4), x(4), data(i, 2), data(i,3));
end
% Show final cost
finalcost=sum(cost)^2;
end



function y = chfun_heston(s0, v0, vbar, a, vvol, r, rho, t, w)
% Heston characteristic function.
% Inputs:
% s0: stock price
% v0: initial volatility (v0^2 initial variance)
% vbar: long-term variance mean
% a: variance mean-reversion speed
% vvol: volatility of the variance process
% r : risk-free rate
% rho: correlation between the Weiner processes for the stock price and its variance
% w: points at which to evaluate the function
% Output:
% Characteristic function of log (St) in the Heston model
% Interim calculations
alpha = -w.*w/2 - i*w/2;
beta = a - rho*vvol*i*w;
gamma = vvol*vvol/2;
h = sqrt(beta.*beta - 4*alpha*gamma); rplus = (beta + h)/vvol/vvol;
rminus = (beta - h)/vvol/vvol; g=rminus./rplus;
% Required inputs for the characteristic function
C = a * (rminus * t - (2 / vvol^2) .* log((1 - g .* exp(-h*t))./(1-g)));
D = rminus .* (1 - exp(-h * t))./(1 - g .* exp(-h*t));

% Characteristic function evaluated at points w
y = exp(C*vbar + D*v0 + i*w*log(s0*exp(r*t)));



function y = call_heston_cf(s0, v0, vbar, a, vvol, r, rho, t, k)
% Heston call value using characteristic functions.
% y = call_heston_cf(s0, v0, vbar, a, vvol, r, rho, t, k)
% Inputs:
% s0: stock price
% v0: initial volatility (v0^2 initial variance)
% vbar: long-term variance mean
% a: variance mean-reversion speed
% vvol: volatility of the variance process
% r: risk-free rate
% rho: correlation between the Weiner processes of the stock price and its variance
% t: time to maturity
% k: option strike
% chfun_heston: Heston characteristic function
% 1st step: calculate pi1 and pi2

% Inner integral 1
int1 = @(w, s0, v0, vbar, a, vvol, r, rho, t, k) real(exp(-i.*w*log(k)).*chfun_heston(s0, v0, vbar, a, vvol, r, rho, t, w-i)./(i*w.*chfun_heston(s0, v0, vbar, a, vvol, r, rho, t, -i)));% inner integral1
int1 = integral(@(w)int1(w,s0, v0, vbar, a, vvol, r, rho, t, k),0,100); % numerical integration
pi1 = int1/pi+0.5; % final pi1

% Inner integral 2:
int2 = @(w, s0, v0, vbar, a, vvol, r, rho, t, k) real(exp(-i.*w*log(k)).*chfun_heston(s0, v0, vbar, a, vvol, r, rho, t, w)./(i*w));
int2 = integral(@(w)int2(w,s0, v0, vbar, a, vvol, r, rho, t, k),0,100);int2 = real(int2);
pi2 = int2/pi+0.5; % final pi2
% 2rd step: calculate call value
y = s0*pi1-exp(-r*t)*k*pi2;
end



% Heston calibration, local optimization (Matlab's lsqnonlin)
% Input on data.txt
% Data = [So, t, k, r, mid price, bid, ask]
clear all;clc;
global data; global cost; global finalcost;
[data] = xlsread('data.xlsx');
% Initial parameters and parameter bounds
% Bounds [v0, Vbar, vvol, rho, 2*a*vbar - vvol^2]
% Last bound include non-negativity constraint and bounds for mean-reversion
x0 = [.5,.5,1,-0.5,1];
lb = [0, 0, 0, -1, 0];
ub = [2, 2, 5, 1, 20];
% Optimization: calls function costf.m:
tic;
x = lsqnonlin(@costf,x0,lb,ub);
toc;
% Solution:
Heston_sol = [x(1), x(2), x(3), x(4), (x(5)+x(3)^2)/(2*x(2))]
x
min = finalcost
```

UPDATE:
I have tried on new data taken from another thesis, here attached, and the code just got 7 out of 24 prices correctly. It seems that somehow the code does not work properly (the code is actually on a publication). Does anyone have any idea on where the problem comes from? Thanks again!

[image]

Comment: Hi, could you please add the result columns to the tables as well? Or maybe a plot of the data and your results? Thanks!

Comment: Another question: shouldn’t the goal read sum(c^2) instead of sum(c)^2 ?

Comment: Yes, you right, it should be c^2. However I obtain very small improvement on the parameters and overall.

Comment: The parameters are now v0=0.0395, vbar=0.0538, vvol=0.8733, rho=-0.9539 and a=7.0832. 
Let's say now I want to check the calibration, so I try to price the call with maturity= 0.1972603, strike= 3800 and rate=0.0433%. Then I input in the Matlab command window the following :call_heston_cf(3830.17, 0.0395, 0.0538, 7.0832, 0.8731, 0.000433, -0.9539, 0.1972603, 3800). But Ans= 153.8467 and as you can see from the table is outside the bid-ask range.

Comment: In the table I uploaded green is when model prices are in the bid - ask range, yellow when they are higher and blue when they are lower than the range. Hope this helps.

Comment: Since you are able to perfectly replicate the results from the paper your code seems fine, no? Have you tried other data sets? Have you tried tweaking the starting points?

Comment: I have tried to filter the data, like reducing moneyness cutting out some maturity ecc. Sometimes I get improvements, but still I cannot price more than 10-20% correctly. However, I haven't tried to change starting parameters. What you you think it would be a good starting parameter set?

Comment: I have updated my question, you are very welcome to check it out if you are interested.